# Code stops after reaching swap function, it works perfectly if I comment it out

Tags: c

The code breaks and doesn't run further after reaching the swap function, even though it works if I comment it out, and I don't see the problem of why it stops working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 10

void swap(int *max,int *minimum);//swaps maximum value location with minimum value location 

void max_min(int arr[],int *max,int *min,int *locmin,int *locmax);

int main()
{
    int grades[10]={40,52,77, 80, 85, 88, 90, 66,55,99};
    int max=0,min=0,locmax,locmin;
    max_min(grades,&max,&min,&locmin,&locmax);//Gets maximum-minimum values and their location
    printf("Largest grade %d\n smallest grade %d\n",max,min);
    swap(&grades[locmax],&grades[locmin]);// only swaps smallest-greatest value  
}      

void swap(int *max,int *minimum)
{
    int temp=*max;
    *max=*minimum;
    *minimum=temp;
}    

void max_min(int arr[],int *max,int *min,int *locmin,int *locmax)
{
    int maxx,minx;
    maxx=arr[0];
    minx=arr[0];
    for (int k = 0; k <size; k++)
    {
        
        for(int i=1; i<size; i++)
        {
            /* If current element is greater than max */
            if(arr[i] > maxx)
            {
                maxx= arr[i];
                *locmax=i;
            }
            
            /* If current element is smaller than min */
            if(arr[i] < minx)
            {
                minx= arr[i];
                *locmin=i;
            }
        }
    }
    *max=maxx;
    *min=minx;
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But even before that, suggest you do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger. Check the value of all variables as it runs, particularly any array indices.

Comment: Please show the code for `maxmin`, preferebly as part of a [mre].  Chances are, `max` and / or `min` are out of range.

Comment: Please provide compiler output if there are errors.
Please explain what you mean by "stops working" 
Do you have to force stop execution? Does it crash and output an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

locmin and locmax are never initialized, neither by main nor by max_min. The result is they will contain whatever garbage was in memory at the time. *If you're lucky* that will be 0, but it could be anything. This can result in locmin or locmax being out out of bounds for the grades array. They're less then 0 or greater than 9. So `grades[locmin]` and `grades[locmax]` try to access memory your process does not own and results in a [memory violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

Looking at max_min(), notice that locmax and locmin are only assigned to conditionally. It may happen that they are *never* assigned to. Specifically ***if the first element of grades is also the smallest element locmin will never be assigned***. It will contain whatever value it started with. If it was never initialized that will be garbage. That is what's happened.

To fix this, initialize them *inside max_min*. Don't make it the caller's responsibility, that is error prone. Also pass in `size`, don't use a global. And probably get rid of the max and min arguments, the caller can get them from locmin and locmax.

```
void max_min(int arr[], size_t size, int *locmin, int *locmax) {
    // At the start, the first element is both the max and min.
    int maxx = arr[0];
    int minx = arr[0];
    *locmax = 0;   // <<<--- initialize to the first index
    *locmim = 0;   // <<<--- initialize to the first index
    
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        for(int i=1; i< size; i++) {
            // If current element is greater than max
            if(arr[i] > maxx) {
                maxx= arr[i];
                *locmax=i; 
            }
            // If current element is smaller than min
            if(arr[i] < minx) {
                minx= arr[i];
                *locmin=i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically locmin was containing a garbage value since the smallest value was in my arr[0], and therefore it's better to usually assign a 0 value for this kind of variable. I would work on making better calls for this kind of problems+not using globals, Thanks for the useful information provided.

Comment: @Lutfi Yes, you've got it. In C, you have to do the initialization yourself. A good compiler will warn you about uninitialized variables. You don't always have to initialize a variable if you're sure it will be overwritten before its read. For example main does not have to initialize locmin and locmax if max_min will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to give an initial value for both locmin,locmax of zero, then the program started working.
I don't know if this is something related to C but it's the first time where I have encountered such a problem.

Comment: Yes, unless you initialize them variables will contain whatever garbage happened to be in memory at the time. We'd need to see `max_min` to know what was assuming the variables were initialized. This probably resulted in locmax and locmin containing values well out of range of the grades array and trying to access `grades[locmax]` and `grades[locmin]` resulted in a [memory violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

Comment: Thank you for this information I'll add the max_min function, to my submitted code.

Comment: That's very hard to read. Would you [edit it into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67664733/edit) please? Where is `size` coming from?

Comment: I'm having a problem with editing my code because of how StackOverflow works this is my first time using it so I have a long way to learn about it. I put my code here if you'd like to have a look, thanks again for your help, and explanation.(https://pastebin.com/756bYQMf)